# findFundamentalMat - epipolar lines are wrong

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I want to compute the fundamental matrix between two image pairs. For that purpose I use SIFT-Features which are matched via the `cv::FlannBasedMatcher`. Afterwards i call `cv::findFundamentalMat(left_pts, right_pts, CV_RANSAC, 2.0, 0.99, ransac_mask)` with the found matches.

To visualize the computed fundamental matrix I want to draw epipolar-lines. To do that I tried the `cv::computeCorrespondEpilines` and a manual mulplication with a Point and extraction of the resulting line equation (ax + by + c = 0).

To draw the lines I simply use that snipped (which I've found in many other examples)

```
for (cv::vector<cv::Vec3f>::const_iterator it = lines1.begin(); it!=lines1.end(); ++it)
{
    cv::line(left_new,
         cv::Point(0,-(*it)[2]/(*it)[1]),
         cv::Point(left.cols,-((*it)[2] + (*it)[0]*left.cols)/(*it)[1]),
         cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
}
```

But corresponding points are not on the epipolar lines. I've even tried it on already rectified images but the lines are not horizontal.

Now i've also tested that example:
http://opencv-cookbook.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter%2009/estimateF.cpp
only to find out that it has the same problem.

Can someone share a working example for such a use-case or give me a hint what could go wrong? (Matchings seem to be fine so it has to be something with the actual estimation)

Comment: Did you verify that the fundamental matrix is correctly computed? This can be done by substitution of points into equality x2'*F*x1=0.

Comment: Okay with that hint it was pretty easy to find the problem: I just had to use the transposed fundamental matrix (or switch the image calculation around). If you add an answer i will accept. Thanks!